# With which parameter can you specify whether a metal is ductile or brittle

Tags: materials, steel, metals, strength

I have to do a durability approval of feather key (shaft-hub connection) and the formulas are dependent if the shaft respectively the hub is ductile or brittle.

But what is the decision about to say it is ductile or brittle.

- My norm for feather key isn’t saying anything how to distinguish if the metal is ductile or brittle.
- The norm for pressfits uses the parameter fracture elongation and reduction of area.
- And the literature is talking about brittle metal when the Maximum Stress Theory is valid $(\sigma_{limit}/\tau_{limit}=1)$ and ductile metal when the Shear Stress Hypothesis is valid $(\sigma_{limit}/ \tau_{limit}=2)$.

  - $\sigma_{limit}$ is tensile strength
  - $\tau_{limit}$ is the strength when plasticity begins

Okay, there are many possibilities… But which one is the right possibility? Or is there a connection between my findings that I’m not aware of?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the material of shaft or hub ? 
What is the working temperature? 
Does any impact force happen during the working of the machine on the shaft or key connection ? And could you please specify the parameters ''fracture elongation and reduction of area" without the exact values difficult to say ? and at what range those parameters remain valid ?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but if the shaft is made of a brittle material you use the brittle formula, and if it's made of a ductile material you use the ductile formula. If you don't know *what* it is made of, then you can't do your "durability approval" at all. There are not "many possibilities" - only two!

Comment: I'm not aware of a hard definition for ductility, it is rather a qualitative description of the material ability to deform plastically before rupture. But as previous comments suggest, the ductility of a given material is also affected by strain rate (how fast you deform it) and temperature.

Comment: @ user190081: That’s exactly what I’m looking for. A hard definition of ductility. The reason why I’m asking this “dump” question is because different norms are using different definitions for ductility. And that’s a little surprising for me. But perhaps I have to say, that I calculated with the basis of “this” norm and therefore the ductility is defined with the parameter fracture elongation.

Comment: @ Sam Farjamirad: The idea of my question is to be more general. When working through a norm at a certain point it is needed to decide if your metal is ductile or brittle. And because different norms have a different definitions of ductility and brittleness there is no hard definition. And that, a hard definition, is exactly what I’m looking for.

Comment: @ alephzero: Can you please explain me if C35 is ductile or brittle? And how do you decide with 24CrMo13-6? … What are the parameters to justify your choice?

Comment: Here is the tip, when you start choosing materials, you need a table, i always do it, I use Rollof-Matek table book. It's written in German but i think you can find a same book (table book) that explains when you may use certain material for certain purposes. I wait for alephzero to give you the answer since you asked him/her at the first place, but if you receive no answer i'll tell you about C35 and ... . Btw this is how mechanical engineers work, material engineers implement more comprehensive methods.

Comment: @ Sam Farjamirad: I would be very thankful if you honor your promise and answer my question :-) I am very interessted how you decide if a metal is ductile or brittle and which are your parameters to justify your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to tell if a metal is ductile or brittle is to look at a fracture surface (e.g. from a tensile or impact test). To have either a ductile or brittle metal defines the failure mechanism which you can tell by having either a [ductile fracture](http://home.jtan.com/~joe/bicycle/images/spoke_2.jpg) or a [brittle fracture](http://vgoinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SEM-Image3.jpg).

Elongation and reduction of area as well as notch toughness (impact test) and hardness testing can give a quantitative value to ductility, by measuring the amount of energy the material absorbs and converts to mechanical deformation. These values are normally used to allow 'design ductility' which is less interested in the failure mechanism and a lot of the time only cares if a material can absorb enough energy not to fail as soon as it is over stressed (or for deliberate deformation). But there isn't a fixed limit for defining a material as ductile or brittle as it depends on the material and is usually used to define a design criteria that must be met.

However if you have an elongation greater than 20% you are probably dealing with a ductile metal, but this can depend on the alloy type/condition and is not always the case for all materials.

Comment: One must define a strain rate before determining if a material is ductile or not. Many carbon steels are ductile in a tensile test and brittle in an impact test.